# Is it advisable to create partitions of different block sizes to categorize files? How does it affect performance?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, 18.10, external-hdd, btrfs

1 and 2 are essentially the same question, but with a slightly different context.

1) Let's say you have an external 1 TB SSD, and you have hundreds of large files like DVDs/Video about 2GB each and millions of small files under 64KB each. Is it advisable to split the 1 TB SSD into two partitions of 700 GB and 300 GB with block sizes of say 8 MB and 4 KB respectively?

2) If you want to optimize your primary drive for read speed and write speed, and your optimization script says you should have a block size of 8 MB for read/write performance....should you partition 100 GB to 200 GB off your primary drive without an OS to exclusively hold small files and give it a block size of 4 or 8 KB? Will that hurt or improve performance?

3) If you have a primary drive of 1 TB SSD and an external drive of 3 TB HDD, is it important to have the block size of the HDD be the same as the same as the block size allocation in the SSD? If not, will it hurt performance?